# Dropping a problematic column from a dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a `dask` dataframe with one problematic column that (I believe) is the source of a particular error that is thrown every time I try to do anything with the dataframe (be it `head`, or `to_csv`, or even when I try to subset using a (different) column. The error is probably owing to a data type mismatch and shows up like this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FIPS'
```

So I decided to drop that column (`'FIPS'`) using

```
df = df.drop('FIPS', axis=1)
```

Now when I do `df.columns`, I don't see `'FIPS'` any longer which I take to mean that it has indeed been dropped. But when I try to write a different column to a file

```
df.column_a.to_csv('example.csv')
```

I keep getting the same error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FIPS'
```

I assume it has something to do with `dask`'s lazy approaches as a result of which it delays the drop, but any work-around would be very helpful.

Basically, I just need to extract a single column (`column_a`) from `df`.

Comment: Have you considered to use a columnar formar as `parquet`? So you can read only the cols you need.

Comment: Do you have a full sample? sometimes if the DAG is cached and corrupt  you may need to restart the kernel/client for a fresh run

Answer (score 0):

try to convert to a pandas dataframe after the drop

```
df.compute()
```

and only then write to csv